# Maven plugin 100% compatible Java21 to generate stub classes from WSDL file and generate *.wsdl from java classes? A solution

Tags: web-services, maven-plugin, spring-boot-3, java-21

We are migrating a lot of project to Java21 SpringBoot 3.2.3 and MongoDB v7 and Maven run with Java21. 

We will use Liberica JDK and Alpaquita Linux of BellSoft as Docker. 

**The one problem that we had was find, in the migration to Java 21, a NOT 100% compatible plugin Maven / dependencies** to generate stub classes with jakarta.* packages, but follow a lot of dependency and maven plugin nobody is 100% compatible from Java 20 forward.

For example **we used below maven plugin/dependencies that have some problem about deprecated but it works fine**:

```java
java.net.URL = new URL("...")
```

instead of using the non-deprecated mode from Java 20:

```java
java.net.URL = Paths.get("...")
                    .toUri()
                    .toURL();
```

**To migrate webservice we had used dependency:**

```xml
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.jvnet.jaxb2.maven2</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-jaxb2-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>0.15.3</version>
</dependency>
```

**and Maven plugin:**

```xml
<build>
    <plugins>
        ...
        <plugin>
            <groupId>com.sun.xml.ws</groupId>
            <artifactId>jaxws-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>4.0.2</version>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>wsimport</goal>
                    </goals>
                </execution>
            </executions>
            <configuration>
                <wsdlDirectory>${project.basedir}/src/main/resources/wsdl</wsdlDirectory>
                <wsdlFiles>
                    <wsdlFile>file.wsdl</wsdlFile>
                </wsdlFiles>
                <sourceDestDir>${project.basedir}/src/main/java</sourceDestDir>
                <packageName>com. ... .stub</packageName>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
        ...
    </plugins>
    <extensions>
        ...
        <extension>
            ...
        </extension>
        ...
    </extensions>
</build>
```

**Somebody know a stable maven plugin or stable dependencies that is 100% compatible with Java21 with javadoc or documentation about version proposed?**

Thanks a lot to support community.

Kind regards